# killing shell process and child oracle process

Tags: oracle, shell, process, background, kill

From my shell script I am killing my background function process using kill command. This function calls SQL procedure using sqlplus:

```
func_foo(){
retval=`sqlplus -s $USER_NAME/$PWD <<EOF
        set pages 0 lines 120 trimout on trimspool on tab off echo off verify off feed off serverout on
        exec pkg_xyz.proc_abc();
        exit;
        EOF`
}


func_foo&
pid_func_foo=$!

sleep 5

kill $pid_func_foo 2>/dev/null
wait $pid_func_foo 2>/dev/null
```

Problem with the approach is that even if my function process is killed, Oracle process keeps on running. Oracle process is not getting killed. I am new to oracle, I am not sure how to handle this scenario. Please provide me with the hint on how to handle this scenario.

Comment: You own and can kill the `sqlplus` process, but when that connects to database an Oracle-owned process is spawned (usually), which you can't kill. Why do you want to kill it? Are you trying to restrict the prcedure execution time to 5 seconds?

Comment: Can you really not kill the Oracle process @Alex. Wouldn't something like `grep sqlplus | grep -v grep | awk '{print kill "$1" }' | sh` whilst connected as the Oracle user work (for killing all SQL*Plus processes - the OP should probably be more discriminating)? Although, [apparently I'm evil](https://blogs.oracle.com/chrisg/entry/grep_piped_into_awk) for using grep piped into awk :-)!

Comment: This is just the sample which I have created to simplify the issue. It is just in some scenario I do want the functionality of function func_foo to be aborted. So I am killing its process. But not sure how to kill the oracle spawned processes.

Comment: @Ben - sure, *if* you're connected as Oracle; I'd assumed the script would be running under another account, so within that you couldn't kill the Oracle process - without `sudo` or other `setuid` program anyway. I'd also rather `alter system kill` the session from within the DB, not least as you could identify the right one to kill. I guess an option is to have a packaged proc that does that, that the user account could call. Sounds like asking for trouble though *8-)

Comment: What I observed was hitting ctrl_c stops oracles porcess spawned by sqlplus process. What does it make stop?

Answer (score 2):

Killing the Oracle processes is a bad idea. Try to solve your problem in another way.

1. Run your procedure as a job, using dbms_scheduler. You can simply stop the job when needed by calling dbms_scheduler.stop_job('job name').
2. Build your procedure so it can be stopped programmatically. I have build a couple of procedures that run for a very long time. Every now and then the procedure checks a table called "Status", containing only one row. If the status is "ok", it runs on. If I change the row to something else, the procedure sees this and stops.

Answer (score 0):

Hitting `control-c` in an interactive SQL*Plus session terminates the running command, generates an informational ORA-01013 message, and leaves you at the SQL*Plus prompt - with the Oracle process still alive but idle (possibly oversimplifying somewhat).

You can get the equivalent effect by sending an interrupt signal, rather than default termination signal. This might vary slightly depending on your OS and shell, but is usually something like:

```
kill -int $pid_func_foo 2>/dev/null
```

This should still generate the ORA-01013 and the `sqlplus` process will continue. But as the next statement in your 'here document' is `exit` it will still stop and will do so more naturally than with a termination signal, and the Oracle session will clear down normally, removing the Oracle process. (If your procedure is doing any inserts or updates, there may still be a delay while the transaction rolls back).

I'm not sure this is a particularly good way to manage execution time limits; job control or resource management might be a better way to go.